# How to use css style for element with class from variable

Tags: jquery

`$button = $(this).attr("class"); 
$fild =$button.replace('button','input'); //will get 'header_form_input'`

How can I apply CSS style for element with class $fild (header_form_input)

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is. When you run this code, will $field get the value "header_form_input"? And do you want to apply some css for that element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the CSS for the jQuery object $fild, just use the jQuery CSS function:

```
$('.' + $fild).css("display", "none");
```

Or if you'll need to change more than one CSS attributes:

```
$('.' + $fild).css({
    color: 'red',
    height: 200
});
```

You can read more about it here:

http://api.jquery.com/css/